# Make Password Field Not Required in Shopify Create Customer Form

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a from on my shopify store that will collect an email address and a "Goal" however I believe the default functionality of shopify requires a password to create an account for the shopify store.  I want to get around the password requirement. I have pasted what I have so far, any help would be amazing.

```
{% form 'create_customer' %}
   {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
      {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
         <script>
            window.location = "https://www.thankyoupage";
          </script>
      {% endif %}

   <div class="clearfix large_form">
       <label for="email" class="login">Email Address</label>
       <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="email" class="large" size="30" />
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix large_form">
      <label for="goal">Goal </label>
      <select name="customer[note][Goal]" id="goal">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Lose Weight">Goal 1 </option>
          <option value="Eat Healthy">Gaol2</option>
          <option value="Peak Performance">Goal 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
     <div class="clearfix large_form" style="display:none;">
        <label for="password" class="login">Password</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="password" class="large password" size="30" is_required="0" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" value="Create">Get Started</button>
 {% endform %}
```

Comment: Password is not required, but without one the user will not be able to login in his account. He will be added in the customer database, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefill the field with a default (random) value, the form check requirements should be satisfied.